# How do I calculate time difference between two time pickers in android?

Tags: android, time, timepicker

I am able to find out the difference between two time intervals, but when the time 1st 12:00am or 00:00 and 2nd time is any other time, I am not getting accurate difference. Instead I am getting a negative difference. Upon debugging I figured out the time is actually taking of the year 1970 January. I am unable to correct it by taking today's time and calculate the difference.

```
package com.cksapp.memoryin;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.Timestamp;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreSettings;

import java.security.CodeSigner;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
//import java.util.Date;

public class HourlyCalculator extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText wage;
    TextView t1, t2, t3;
    ImageView i1, i2;
    Button b1;
    int minutestotal;
    String timex, timey;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculator_hourly);
        wage = findViewById(R.id.hourlyrate);
        t1 = findViewById(R.id.starttimetext);
        t2 = findViewById(R.id.endtimetext);
        t3 = findViewById(R.id.finaltime);
        i1 = findViewById(R.id.startimage);
        i2 = findViewById(R.id.endimage);
        b1 = findViewById(R.id.calculatebutton);


        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        final int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        final int mins = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        i1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final TimePickerDialog time = new TimePickerDialog(HourlyCalculator.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay1, int minute1) {
                        timex = hourOfDay1 + ":" + minute1;
                        t1.setText(timex);
                        Log.d("Time1", timex);
                    }
                },hour, mins, true);
                time.show();
            }
        });

       i2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               final TimePickerDialog time2 = new TimePickerDialog(HourlyCalculator.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                       timey = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
                       t2.setText(timey);
                       Log.d("Time1", timey);
                   }
               },hour,mins,true);
               time2.show();
           }
       });
       b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
               try {
                   Date a = sdf.parse(timex);
                   Date b = sdf.parse(timey);
                   long difference = a.getTime() - b.getTime();
                   Log.d("Time", String.valueOf(difference));
                  /* minutestotal = (int) (difference/60000);
                   Log.d("Timearey", String.valueOf(minutestotal));
                   int totalwageinitital = Integer.parseInt(wage.getText().toString());
                  double totalwagepermin = totalwageinitital/60;
                  double finalprice = minutestotal * totalwagepermin;

                   t3.setText(String.valueOf(finalprice));*/
               } catch (ParseException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing the time using only hours and minutes, without providing the year, month and day the sdf will assume Jan 1st, 1970.

You should do this in a different way: initialize a calendar object for each date using Calendar.getInstance(), this will give you an instance with today's date, then set the hours and minutes for those 2 instances according to the hours and minutes in the picker and check the difference between their timeInMilliseconds.

```
Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example about how do I initialise calendar object for each date using Calendar.getInstance. Thanks!

Comment: But, I have initialised in the above way in onCreate method. If that is not relevant modification to be performed kindly point out in my code where the changes have to be performed. Thanks!

Comment: You should do this in your onTimeSet callback and save the result in a field (instead of the string you save now. then you can do the comparison between two calendar objects on your onClick